# No output from nmap script

Tags: nmap, nse

I'm trying to use the nmap script `ssl-dh-params` to identify what specific 1024-bit Diffie-Hellman group a TLS server is using.  However, the script is not giving me any output at all and I can't figure out why:

```
C:\Users\user3553031>nmap -p 1234 --script=ssl-dh-params 10.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-07-09 17:55 Pacific Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for somehost.somedomain (10.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.022s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
1234/tcp open  unknown
MAC Address: 01:01:01:01:01:01 (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.34 seconds
```

I know that there is a TLS listener on that port and that it supports DHE ciphersuites: the script `ssl-enum-ciphers` gives output including the following:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE REASON
1234/tcp open  unknown syn-ack ttl 55
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings:
|       Key exchange (dh 1024) of lower strength than certificate key
|_  least strength: A
```

That also tells me that scripting is not completely broken in my nmap build.  I know that the script is installed because when I try to run a script with a nonsense name, I get an error.  So it seems that the preconditions to `ssl-dh-params` are satisfied.  Yet I get no output from it, or from nmap to indicate that tried to run that script at all, even when I run nmap with `-vvvvv -ddddd`.

What's going on?  Am I making some mistake?  Is the script broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nmap's scripts require the "rule" function to return true before they will run against a target. The rule function for `ssl-dh-params` checks for common SSL port numbers, but also for whether version detection (`-sV`) found SSL present. You can get it to work on any port easily by adding `-sV`, or if you are in a hurry, `-sV --version-light`.

Because `ssl-enum-ciphers` is a very popular script that people often request to run on unusual ports, we expanded the rule function for that script to also send some SSL-detecting probes if version detection was not requested. We didn't make this change to other `ssl-*` scripts because fewer users complained of missing results in this way. We'll consider adding this to other scripts in the future.

EDIT: Today I moved the extra probing code from `ssl-enum-ciphers` into the `shortport.ssl` function so that all SSL/TLS-related scripts can work the same way. The probes will only be sent once per port; the result is cached and will be checked by the other scripts as needed. Watch for it in the next Nmap release.

Comment: It doesn't work for me with -sV on port 443 on a host which has DH TLS ciphers...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the script source code in /usr/share/nmap/scripts.

From what I can see it seems to have a portrule i.e. a rule that deciedes if the script is actually applicable for this port:

```
portrule = function(host, port)
  return shortport.ssl(host, port) or sslcert.getPrepareTLSWithoutReconnect(port)
end
```

From the [doucmentation](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/shortport.html#ssl) it would seem that shortport.ssl checks if the port is a common ssl port. So maybe that is the issue here. Try copying the NSE Script and modifying the return line (I did not test this myself):

```
portrule = function(host, port)
  return shortport.port_or_service(1234,"ssl")
end
```

Check out the [NSE Script Writing Tutorial](https://nmap.org/book/nse-tutorial.html) for more info on rules.

Comment: I modified it to always return true and the script still doesnt execute